# Unnesting JSON using R

Tags: r, json

Source=https://jsonformatter.org/e038ec

The above is nested json.

I want the output to be as below:

dataElements.name, dataElements.id, categoryOptionCombos.name, categoryOptionCombos.id

Any help in r?

---

Top 3 elements:

```
{"dataElements":[{"name":"097b-A.10 VHT Total number of pregnant women","id":"qaBd9CL3BdC","categoryCombo":{"name":"Sex","id":"WPZ1vwTw6XW","categoryOptionCombos":[{"name":"Total","id":"sSBjJ8kJfLu"},{"name":"(Male)","id":"Br7LEiVn608"},{"name":"(Female)","id":"Al5qBHW0OlA"}]}},{"name":"097b-A.11 VHT Number of deliveries at home","id":"ciWX588rl8K","categoryCombo":{"name":"Sex","id":"WPZ1vwTw6XW","categoryOptionCombos":[{"name":"Total","id":"sSBjJ8kJfLu"},{"name":"(Male)","id":"Br7LEiVn608"},{"name":"(Female)","id":"Al5qBHW0OlA"}]}},{"name":"097b-A.12 VHT Number of women who died within 6 weeks after delivery","id":"EnYHpQevFvb","categoryCombo":{"name":"Sex","id":"WPZ1vwTw6XW","categoryOptionCombos":[{"name":"Total","id":"sSBjJ8kJfLu"},{"name":"(Male)","id":"Br7LEiVn608"},{"name":"(Female)","id":"Al5qBHW0OlA"}]}}]}
```

Comment: Fred, have you tried anything? `jsonlite` is a good package for doing this, and often gets it close-to-right.

Comment: Fred, I suggested an edit for your question that includes the top 3 (of over 100) elements in the json list. It's preferred to keep questions self-contained, as when external links go stale (expire, get deleted), the question becomes unreproducible. It also presents a much smaller problem to solve, as I believe that a solution here can do 100 elements as easily as it does 3. Lastly, since it appears that your intended output is discarding data from the lists, it would help a lot if you could (1) confirm discarding, and (2) give expected output *given this sample data*. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a combination with `jsonlite` and `tidyr`.

Starting with that file downloaded (top 3 list elements) as `"jsonformatter.txt"`:

```r
js <- jsonlite::read_json("jsonformatter.txt", simplifyDataFrame = TRUE, flatten = TRUE)
# Warning: JSON string contains (illegal) UTF8 byte-order-mark!
length(js)
# [1] 1
length(js[[1]])
# [1] 3

js <- js[[1]]
names(js)[1:2]
# [1] "name" "id"  
names(js)[1:2] <- paste0("dataElements.", names(js)[1:2])

tidyr::unnest(js, categoryCombo.categoryOptionCombos)
# # A tibble: 9 x 6
#   dataElements.name                                                    dataElements.id categoryCombo.name categoryCombo.id name     id         
#   <chr>                                                                <chr>           <chr>              <chr>            <chr>    <chr>      
# 1 097b-A.10 VHT Total number of pregnant women                         qaBd9CL3BdC     Sex                WPZ1vwTw6XW      Total    sSBjJ8kJfLu
# 2 097b-A.10 VHT Total number of pregnant women                         qaBd9CL3BdC     Sex                WPZ1vwTw6XW      (Male)   Br7LEiVn608
# 3 097b-A.10 VHT Total number of pregnant women                         qaBd9CL3BdC     Sex                WPZ1vwTw6XW      (Female) Al5qBHW0OlA
# 4 097b-A.11 VHT Number of deliveries at home                           ciWX588rl8K     Sex                WPZ1vwTw6XW      Total    sSBjJ8kJfLu
# 5 097b-A.11 VHT Number of deliveries at home                           ciWX588rl8K     Sex                WPZ1vwTw6XW      (Male)   Br7LEiVn608
# 6 097b-A.11 VHT Number of deliveries at home                           ciWX588rl8K     Sex                WPZ1vwTw6XW      (Female) Al5qBHW0OlA
# 7 097b-A.12 VHT Number of women who died within 6 weeks after delivery EnYHpQevFvb     Sex                WPZ1vwTw6XW      Total    sSBjJ8kJfLu
# 8 097b-A.12 VHT Number of women who died within 6 weeks after delivery EnYHpQevFvb     Sex                WPZ1vwTw6XW      (Male)   Br7LEiVn608
# 9 097b-A.12 VHT Number of women who died within 6 weeks after delivery EnYHpQevFvb     Sex                WPZ1vwTw6XW      (Female) Al5qBHW0OlA
```